# How do I decode curl url encoded string in a C++ server

Tags: php, c++, curl, post, server

I am using the c++ pastiche rest api library to make a rest api in ubuntu linux.
I have got the server to work without problems. I can use php curl to post data to my server. The server receives the data and can return the data.
The problem is this. When I post to the server with curl post it sends it to the server in a url encoded string like this `name=percy&age=34&eye_color=blue`.
I need to know how to in C++ put each one into a string.
Also one of the fields may also have binary data as well as ordinary strings. I have already written the code to interpret the binary data, but I don't know how to convert the string from curl post at the moment.
Please ignore the fact my port is different in my php. The reason is that I am running ubuntu in virtualbox.

I need to extract strings and binary data from the post I am sending. This is what I don't know how to do.
I am not sure if I may need another library to do this, or not

Here is my php code:-

```
$postData = http_build_query(
            array(
                'dstdata' => 'hello',
                'more' => 'test',
                'age' => 34
            )
        );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'localhost:9999/about');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($output);       
        curl_close($ch);
```

The above code would make a string like this  `dstdata=hello&more=test&age=34`

And here the c++ server code. You can see I have two routes setup here:-

```
#include <pistache/router.h>
#include "pistache/endpoint.h"
#include "pistache/http.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace Pistache;
using namespace Rest;

Rest::Router router;

void sausage(const Rest::Request& request, Http::ResponseWriter response){
    std::cout << "We have contact" << std::endl;
    response.send(Http::Code::Ok, "Bottoms Up\n");
}

void about(const Rest::Request& request, Http::ResponseWriter response){
    std::cout << "Server Running" << std::endl;
    response.send(Http::Code::Ok, request.body());
}

int main(){
    Routes::Get(router,"/ready",Routes::bind(&sausage));
    Routes::Post(router,"/about",Routes::bind(&about));
    Pistache::Address addr(Pistache::Ipv4::any(), Pistache::Port(9080));
    auto opts = Pistache::Http::Endpoint::options()
        .threads(10).flags(
        Pistache::Tcp::Options::ReuseAddr);
    Http::Endpoint server(addr);
    server.init(opts);
    server.setHandler(router.handler());
    server.serve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curl encoded URLs shouldn't differ from any others if used correctly. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: I don't know how to convert the encoded string so that I can access one string. For instance I might want to put the age into an int, or maybe a name into a string, but I am not sure how. Also one of the objects in the array I am sending might be binary which I have to parse as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question now, but I had to change the way I sent the data. Instead of sending the data as formdata I sent it json encoded like this.

```
<?php
$data = array("name" => "Paul", "age" => "38");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('localhost:9999/newtest');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                    
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Then I installed the nlohmann json library. This example I have shown lets me post to my server as json data. I have json parsed it, and put it into a sentence and returned the sentence. So the server is now doing what I want, I can now write my real code. Because I am using json encoding I can also use this to send binary data as well. So it looks like I have solved my problem.

```
#include <pistache/router.h>
#include "pistache/endpoint.h"
#include "pistache/http.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace Pistache;
using namespace Rest;
Rest::Router router;

void newtest(const Rest::Request& request, Http::ResponseWriter response){
    std::cout << "NewTest" << std::endl;
    auto jj = json::parse(request.body());
    std::string name = jj["name"];
    std::string age =jj["age"];
    std::string test = name+" is my name, and my age is "+age;
    response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, test);
}

int main(){
    Routes::Post(router,"/newtest",Routes::bind(&newtest));
    Pistache::Address addr(Pistache::Ipv4::any(), Pistache::Port(9080));
    auto opts = Pistache::Http::Endpoint::options()
        .threads(10).flags(
        Pistache::Tcp::Options::ReuseAddr);
    Http::Endpoint server(addr);
    server.init(opts);
    server.setHandler(router.handler());
    server.serve();
    return 0;
}
```